# Get values of Firestore documents

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore, go-templates

I am trying to use Firestore as my backend to store document data. 
The response from Firestore to

```
docs, _ := q.Documents(ctx).GetAll()
```

is of type

```
var docs []*firestore.DocumentSnapshot
```

Assuming my document has the struture

```
map[array:[a b] text:bla]
```

How can I access the values in the `*firestore.DocumentSnapshot`?

I see a result when

```
for _, doc := range docs {
    fmt.Println(doc.Data())
}
```

get's executed and it prints

```
map[array:[a b] text:bla]
```

```
func g() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, _ := firestore.NewClient(ctx, "myapp")

    defer client.Close()

    q := client.Collection("my").
        Limit(10)

    docs, _ := q.Documents(ctx).GetAll()

    for _, doc := range docs {
        fmt.Println(doc.Data())
    }
}
```

I would like to use the values in a http template in my application in a slice of struct.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly convert it to your struct using `doc.DataTo`

Sample:

```
var articles []ArticleModel // slice
var model ArticleModel
    if err := doc.DataTo(&model); err != nil {
            // TODO: Handle error.
    }
articles = append(articles, model)
```